# How do I update the Readme.md on NuGet.org via API?

Tags: nuget, readme, nugetgallery

I have a situation where I need to update more than 30 packages that each have 15 versions with current info and continually keep them updated. While it is now recommended to add a Readme (markdown) file to the NuGet package before uploading, that doesn't help because my packages are already on NuGet.org.

The NuGet dashboard has a [feature that lets me preview and update the Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/package-readme-on-nuget-org#preview-your-readme) and then publish it, which is exactly what I need, except I need to make some tweaks for each version of each package and it would be a ton of work using this feature if I just needed to make a small update on every Readme.md page. Unfortunately, updating is disabled when pushing a package that contains a Readme.md page, so the only way I have found to edit the Readme.md after the NuGet package is pushed is to exclude it from the package entirely.

I went through the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource) and I see there are APIs for downloading metadata and uploading packages, but I haven't found any that allow updating metadata that is already an "overridden" version of the original info that the NuGet package contained.

Does an API for updating the Readme markdown of a NuGet package exist and if so, how do I call it?

Comment: Do you want to update only readme after publish or can you update readme as part of the package. I think publishing a new version should allow updating readme as part of the process but documentation is not clear.

Comment: I want to update the Readme for an existing version, not upload a new version. Unfortunately, after further experimentation, I have discovered that publishing a Readme.md file with the NuGet package will disable the ability to edit it in the dashboard. So, if we have data on the readme that may change over time, the only solution to edit it appears to be to exclude the readme from the NuGet package and copy the data into the dashboard after the package is pushed.